# Why does the demonym "Canadian" appear irregular?

Tags: history, demonyms

In particular -

Given that people from America are Americans, why are people from Canada not *Canadans?

I'm in search of a historical and etymological answer, addressing questions such as the date and context of the first usage of the demonym, whether there was any variation in the form used initially, brief description (if such is possible) of usage of "-ian" versus "-an".

Comment: There are no rules in English - there is only general guidance - English is a language of exceptions. Consonant + ia -> Chechnia -Chechnian; Cambodia - Cambodian But consonant + a ->Canada - Canadian; Argentina - Argentinian. It seems that "-ian" is a preferred suffix.

Comment: Argentinian is a solecism, albeit one that's been around since at least 1982. The people are Argentines, and the adjective is Argentine.

Comment: You can find why Canada is called Canada on Wikipedia. As to why not Canadia, lots of places end in both -ia and consonant+a but most countries which end -ia have that ending or a similar ending in their native language (e.g. Cyrillic *ija*) or it comes from Latin, and just -a is common and unobjectionable. So -ia wouldn't be more correct. Why Canadian is probably because suffix -ian sounds slightly more natural or more common for demonyms; compare Panama->Panamanian (not every place has a demonym or a widely used one - I've met more Canadians than Bermudans).

Comment: @greybeard I suppose I'm looking more for a historical/etymological explanation, and I should make that clear - when/by whom was "Canadian" first used? Are there any early instances of "Canadian"/"Canadan" alternation? That sort of thing.

Comment: @AndrewLeach So they say - few take much notice.

Comment: @MattGutting There are no early instance of Canadan. The place name is apparently first attested in French in 1545 and subsequently in English from the mid 16th cent.; the French name is apparently ultimately < St Lawrence Iroquoian *canada* = town (now phonemicized as kaná:taʔ). **Canadian** -*Etymology*: < the name of Canada (see Canada n.1) + -ian suffix, after Middle French, French canadien (1557 as noun, 1575 or earlier as adjective).

Comment: "Italy/Italian" against "Germany/*Germanian" is another interesting pair to look at, but a slightly different question perhaps.

Comment: Swedish, Danish, Norwegian. English, Irish. Scottish.